# Is there an easy way to extend an attribute directive in angularjs?

Tags: angularjs

I want to make a custom `ng-if` but can't find any good examples of how that should be done.

What I'm aiming for is:

```
<div my-if="someText">....</div>
```

I want that to expand to

```
<div ng-if="true|false">....</div>
```

where `true|false` depends on `someText`. Is there an easy way to do this?

Comment: why don't you call a function over `ng-if` directive itself, which will decide value `true/false` like `ng-if="check()"` and then function will be `$scope.check = function(){ return someText == 'something' }`

Comment: I want to use it for feature toggling, so I want a simpler way to just write `toggle-if="mytogglename"`.

Comment: ng-if is VERY hard to extend/reuse... ng-show is easier, as you can use `display:none` and roll your own...

Comment: ...and, in addition to what Pankaj Parkar writes above, you can use one-time bindings to eliminate the watch, if that is your need: `ng-if="::check()"`. This is useful for feature toggling.

Comment: are you want to only `show/hide` or  dom `generate/destroy` using your directive ?

Comment: I think function is ok. If you so, so want your code to look simple, may be watch some precompiler to replace my-if="test" to ng-if="'test' == 'something'"?

Comment: @malix, I wouldn't go as far to say it is VERY hard, see my own answer below: http://stackoverflow.com/a/36174574/280693. You just have to know what to do.

Comment: Indeed, I know, VERY is a bit too strong, but I meant it has a lot of pitfalls and performance gotchas...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To replace a directive with an `ng-if` a recompile is needed. The easiest way I get it working was this:

```
(function () {
   angular.module('enheter').directive('toggleIf',['$compile', function($compile) {
            return {
                restrict: 'A',
                compile: function(el,attr) {
                    var toggleName = attr.toggleIf;
                    var toggleOn = toggleName === "sometext";
                    el.attr('ng-if', toggleOn);
                    el.removeAttr('toggle-if');
                    var fn = $compile(el);
                    return function(scope) {
                        fn(scope);
                    };
                }
            };
        }]); 
})();
```

The directive above first get the value of the `toggleIf` attribute. The part that define the value of `toggleOn` will be more complex, but this shows what I was aiming for. Then I just add the `ng-if` to the element and remove the `toggle-if`. If the `toggle-if` was not removed there would be an infinite loop since the call to `$compile` would execute this function again and again.

Answer (score -1):

```
<div ng-if="showText ? true : false">....</div>
```

but then again, if your showText is a boolean, it will do the same thing.

Comment: You're not even trying to answer my question.

Comment: you are saying "where true|false depends on someText".  you can try to have a better question as well.

Comment: I think I made it quite clear. Depending on the value provided to my directive I want that to expand to an `ng-if` corresponding to that value.

Comment: Right, hence the constant flow of answers :)  I still don't understand the usecase for this.  If this ng-if is nested under the my-if directive you can pass the boolean variable anyways.  Otherwise, if under another directive, then just use events.

Comment: SomeText is not a boolean variable. It is some text that I want to use to determine if I should be true or false decided by some logic. In my example solution the logic is simple to illustrate this. I will use it to do feature toggling I'm the application.